# Getting rows maintaining the order of the IDs passed

Tags: mysql

I have this clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM picture p
 WHERE p.id IN (2, 1, 3)
```

When I execute it I get the 3 elements, but ordered by its 'id' (`1,2,3`).

What I want is to get the elements in base of the order I'm giving: `2,1,3`.

Comment: Can you do it in script side?

Comment: How are you consuming that data? In which language? php, c#, ruby, and so on ...

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean..I'm using php so I think I will do a foreach of array(2,1,3). Thanks.

Comment: Quit signing your posts please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I execute it I get the 3 elements, but ordered by its 'id'
>   (1,2,3).

Not really. You basically get an arbitrary order. No `ORDER BY` clause means no reliable order.

If you are building your SQL dynamically, you'll have to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM picture p
WHERE p.id IN (2, 1, 3)
ORDER BY CASE p.id
    WHEN 2 THEN 1
    WHEN 1 THEN 2
    WHEN 3 THEN 3
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `CASE` you can also use **[`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)** function:

```
SELECT   *
  FROM   picture p
 WHERE   p.id IN (2, 1, 3)
ORDER BY FIELD(p.id, 2, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     *
FROM         picture p
WHERE
p.id = 2

UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         picture p
WHERE
p.id = 1

UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         picture p
WHERE
p.id = 3
```

source : [Click here](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:31095)

And kindly don't use "*" in SELECT statement it's bad practice; try to read about rule of thumb for database optimization.

Comment: That `ORDER BY id` statement at the end is peculiar, since it undoes what you were trying to achieve with UNIONs.

Comment: If he wants all the fields, then `*` is just fine.